# client-side form validation after clicking SUBMIT

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, client-side-validation

I have 2 php files "source.php" and "target.php". In the source.php part I have,

```
<form method="POST" id="form1" action="target.php">
...
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

When I click on submit it goes to the "target.php" (even if I have errors in the form), but I want that, only after all form fields are validated it will go to the target page, else it shows some kind of warning message and stays on the same page. Please help! Maybe this is a stupid question for some but I am a beginner. (I know how to do all the field validations and its working fine).

Comment: You need to validate them using Javascript. Read this http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/validation.shtml

Comment: `type="submit"` and no `type="sumbit"`

Comment: In case you submit form to another file, you will need to validate form in javascript and prevent submitting on errors, otherwise your form will be directed to second file.

Comment: [HTML5 has a lot of form validation.](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-form-validation/) Even regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of duplicate questions.Please search throughly before you post next time.

Generally javascripts are used for validation.But there are cases when javascripts become inefficient,for example when you need to validate country and its states.Its not practical to send the entire list of countries and states to the client. In such scenarios AJAX is used.By using AJAX the client sends the data to server immediatly after the user enters it.then it fetch only the required data.Its a simultaneous two way communication between client and server.for example if the user enters country name as INDIA,using AJAX states of INDIA are loaded for validation,thus saving bandwidth.
JavaScript and AJAX are not easy to learn,you must research try and correct different codes.Just google "JavaScript form validation"...

This is from w3Schools...

Required Fields
The function below checks if a field has been left empty. If the field is blank, an alert box alerts a message, the function returns false, and the form will not be submitted:

```
function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
       alert("First name must be filled out");
       return false;
    }
}
```

The function above could be called when a form is submitted:

Example

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

here is more basic examples **http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp**

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to validate your form. JavaScript is not recommended for form validation.
A simple tutorial for AJAX Validation is available [here](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/index.html?p=6.html)

But be aware, even if you are validating your form before submission to target.php, always make sure that you check the data in target.php too. This is because JavaScript can be changed (thanks to the modern DOM interpreters) in the browser. It can be made so that the form is submitted without AJAX verification. So you should check it twice, before and after submission.

Also make sure to escape the data, as user input can never be trusted.
You should also user `strip_tags($string)` to prevent use from inserting php code.

Comment: No, using ajax to validate a form before you actually post the form is a bad idea. It means you're actually doing two round trips to the server to post the form, where the first one already sends all the data. Using javascript for client side validation is just fine. But whether or not you use client side validation, you **always** must use server side validation.

Comment: @Arjan By ajax validation, I mean checking for username availability, proper email format etc. But yes, one must ALWAYS use server side validation, as we do not know what the data is. It may be anything, php code, SQL injection technique, etc.

Comment: True, you could use ajax to check for user name availability. But then you should do that when the user has entered a user name, not when he wants to submit the form. (And there are some security issues, since it would be very easy to go through a list of user names and find out which ones are taken.) Besides, you still need to validate the user name upon form submission. I also forgot to mention that `strip_tags()` is the wrong solution for a potential problem. (Inserting php code is only an issue if you use `eval()`.) `echo strip_tags('foo<bar');` prints out `foo`.

Comment: @Arjan Yes what you are saying is also true. I generally use the ajax username check on jQuery blur. And yes I was wrong about `strip_tags` .

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is most likely the easiest way to do this (read the other posts).

However, if you don't want to use JavaScript you could always check if all forms are set using `isset()` or something similar and then passing on the `$_POST` variables in the URL and grabbing those using `$_GET`. Of course make sure there isn't any sensitive information in the URL. In addition: you could always work with global variables.

Another way to do this without JavaScript is submit to a database after several checks (like escaping the strings etc.), perhaps even encrypt, but I don't suggest this since this is the long way around.